# UNIX command and output in a single delimited file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Is there a way to get the command that is being executed and the result of the command in the same output file?

i want a output file

**command1** 'some kind of delimiter' **output** 'New line'

**command2** 'some kind of delimiter' **output** 'New line'

**command3** 'some kind of delimiter' **output** 'New line'

is this possible ???
please guide me on achiving this ...

Comment: make a shell script (`echo` then command etc)?

Comment: The usual way of making an archive copy of commands run and their output is to use `script`.  See `man 1 script`.  It generates a log file that resembles the terminal interaction that you see.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your command is but here's the sample i have taken to be ls command just for illustration purpose.

```
ls script.sh >> temp; echo $(history | tail -2 | head -1 | awk '{print $2}' && cat temp) && rm -rf temp
```

What it does is:

command ls redirects output to a temp file (remember i don't know your command and ls is just a sample so you have output stored in temp file)

second command - just grabs your last command that you executed in this case it would be ls and output of the command that we stored

and finally you delete the file that you just created.